# Как взять картинку из сообщения и отправить её?

Tags: discord, discord.py, pillow, pil

Хочу сделать что-то по типу сшакаливания картинки в Discord.Py, но у меня чуточку не получается.

Вот код:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def шакал(self, ctx):
        if len(ctx.message.attachments) > 0:
            img = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
            img.save('example.png')
            await ctx.send(file=discord.File('example.png'))
            os.remove('example.png')
        else:
            await ctx.send('даун картинку добавь')
```

А так-же ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'
```

(заранее попрошу не бить за код, я особо не шарю в PIL)

Comment: А да, интересный факт, пока я не добавил сшакаливание, а лишь сохранение и отправку картинки. Я пока тестирую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как насчёт библиотеки `Pillow`?

```
import requests
from PIL import Image

@commands.command()
    async def шакал(self, ctx):
        if len(ctx.message.attachments) > 0:
            img = Image.open(requests.get(ctx.message.attachments[0].url, stream=True).raw)
            img.save('example.png')
            await ctx.send(file=discord.File('example.png'))
            os.remove('example.png')
        else:
            await ctx.send('добавьте изображение, пожалуйста.')
```

Comment: Че-е-е-е-ел, спасибо огромное! Уважаю.

Comment: А можешь сказать, как изменить качество этой картинки?

Comment: Вроде как при охранении указываешь параметр `quality`, посмотри доки